# Xamarin Android Using Handler crashes randomly Unable to activate instance of type Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor from native handle

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am using Xamarin Android Native to create a worker handler using postdelay to run some background data fetching from webservice, the handler would call a function every few seconds, but when the activity runs, the app crashes randomly, and the FATAL EXCEPTION stack trace did not specify where exactly the problem is and every time it just throw the same message: "android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor from native handle"

Following is the detail stack-trace:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ..., PID: 23551
    android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor from native handle 0xffd76a6c (key_handle 0x5005665). ---> System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor::.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership) ---> Java.Interop.JavaLocationException: Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown.
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
      at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateProxy (System.Type type, System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00054] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
      at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateInstance (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type targetType) [0x00111] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
      at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateInstance (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type targetType) [0x0017d] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
      at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type type) [0x000b9] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
      at Java.Lang.Object._GetObject[T] (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00017] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
      at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject[T] (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00000] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
      at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject[T] (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00006] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
      at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00000] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 
        at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.eac9d564-b7f8-4035-a2ff-b38fdb337e7b(intptr,intptr)
        at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
        at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:30)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Who has encounter the same before?
And how to resolve this issue?

Your help is so much appreciated.

Comment: There is discussion https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/156, you can try to clean your project and rebuild again

Comment: Thanks Cherry. I have finally found the cause, the reason i get the above error was my mistake, I actually have 2 handler which the 1st handler postdelayed the 1st callback runnable and the 1st callback runnable invoked the 2nd handler to invoke the 2nd runnable and the 2nd runnable invoked the 1st handler.... this loop continues. And the ondestroy method of this background service would remove the call back of each handler.

Comment: So here are the mistakes, i mis-calling the removecallback of 1st runnable to the 2nd handler, and 2nd runnable to the 1st handler, and that is the main cause, bcz i removecallback the the runnable that has never called postdelayed.